# How to properly set a MongoDb index, when I query on multiple fields and then perform a sort

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let us assume I have a collection with these fields: A, B, C, D, S

These are the queries I might perform: A or A + B or A + B + C or A + C and I always want to sort my results by S. What indexes are required to cover all my queries?

Comment: looks like at least A needs to be indexed no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For filtering

`ABC` and `AC` is enough to avoid just the collection scan

But if you want to avoid in-memory sorting as well

You need to create all the following indexes

```
AS
ABS
ABCS
ACS
```

Comment: To add on to this, if B or C are going to be queried by range operators, you might think about putting them after S. I like mlab's sorting advice -- https://docs.mlab.com/indexing/#sorting-efficiently

Comment: Mani is completely right about the necessary indexes, but keep in mind that this really depends on what these fields are and what query patterns you're planning on using! If B or C has much higher cardinality than A, it might make sense to put those fields first. If you have memory pressure, you might want to omit some of those indexes. Depending on what your data actually looks like, an index like `ASBC` might be good enough.

Comment: Keep in mind, if you're already putting 4 of 5 fields into an index, you might consider putting `D` into the index as well so that queries can be "covered."  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query

Comment: @willis For ASBC, In this case, we don't even to need to include B and C. Because as Markus mentioned in the question, S will be used only in the SORT clause, not in EQUALITY check. So in this case, just AC is enough.

Comment: check out https://docs.mlab.com/indexing/#sorting-efficiently -- if B & C are range restrictions, you can put them _after_ the sort. Sorts often go last, but they don't always have to.

Comment: @willis Yes. you are correct. Thanks for the mlab link. So the rule of thumb is EQUALITY SORT RANGE.